# React Natvie buttons and textInput not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

Since the `<Modal>` in React Native is kinda iffy, I've made my own with a `<View>` that renders when this.state.display is true. But the text input and button doesn't do anything when clicked / interacted with.

I've tried using a regular `<Modal>` but prefer my way. As well as changing the actual style of the  modal. I've added different onPresses and a few other minor code adjustments that haven't worked.

```
  shouldRender() {
    if (this.state.display) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.modal}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Event Title"
            onChangeText={title => this.setState({title})}
            value={this.state.title}
            style={styles.textInput}
           />
          <TextInput />
          <Button />
          <Button /> //the other buttons and textinput has similar things
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return <View></View>;
    }
  }
```

In the render method:

```
return(
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={this.addReminder}
  style={styles.reminderTouch}>
  <Text style={styles.reminderBtn}>+</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
)
```

And the addReminder method just sets this.state.display to true

I'm looking for the buttons to submit / close the modal and the text input to change the title and text state. Right now, the buttons don't animate on press and the text inputs can't be clicked.

Also, prior to the modal, when the textinputs where just on screen, everything worked fine.

Comment: A little more details would be nice. can you show the entirety of your components involved?

Comment: Here is a link to the full component: https://jsfiddle.net/x01qobuL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description sounds like an issue with zIndex - something is being rendered over top of your modal if the button opacity and input focus are not working.

I would try moving the `<View>{this.shouldRender()}</View>` to be the final child in the containing `<View>` in your render method and if that doesn't work then up the `zIndex`.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. The buttons and textInput are still not working.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read carefully enough - my mistake! Your description sounds like an issue with `zIndex` - something is being rendered over top of your modal if the opacity and focus on the elements don't even work right. I would try moving the `<View>{this.shouldRender()}</View>` to be the final child in the containing `<View>` in your render method and if that doesn't work then upping the `zIndex`. But definitely seems like something is capturing the tap events instead of your custom modal.

Comment: I tried both and the zIndex option didn't seem to change anything but putting the ```<View>{this.shouldRender()}</View>``` at and towards the end, it wouldn't render at all on click and even when I set it to display permanently.

Comment: Hey @MaxTully I noticed you marked my answer correct but what is still there was definitely not the solution - is there part of one of my comments that helped that I include in the original answer?

Comment: Yep, the reason it seemed my modal wasn't rendering when I moved it to the bottom was because it was off the screen, after realigning it to the top, everything works great

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this inside your render()

```
render(){
  return(
  <Modal visible={this.state.display} style={styles.modal}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Event Title"
        onChangeText={title => this.setState({title})}
        value={this.state.title}
        style={styles.textInput}
       />
      <TextInput />
      <Button />
      <Button /> //the other buttons and textinput has similar things
  </Modal>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={this.setState({display: true})}
    style={styles.reminderTouch}>
    <Text style={styles.reminderBtn}>+</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 )
}
```

this modal will only display if this.state.disaply == true

Comment: I've tried this, but even when the modals visibility is hidden, it displays. I prefer this way as it's more customizable and more predictable.